# Ошибка C2660 idealne: функция не принимает 1 аргументов HELP!

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int idealne()
{
    int col=0;
    int *A=new int[1000];
    int rezult = 0;
    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 0;
    int n3 = 0;
    int n4 = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        n1 = 0;
        n2 = 0;
        n3 = 0;
        n4 = 0;
        int g = i;
        do {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                i / 2;
                n1 = n1 + 2;
            }
            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                i / 3;
                n2 = n2 + 3;
            }
            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                i / 5;
                n3 = n3 + 5;
            }
            if (i % 7 == 0)
            {
                i / 7;
                n4 = n4 + 7;
            }
            else
            {
                i = 1;
            }

            rezult = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4;
        } while (i!=1);

        int b = rezult+1;
        if (g == b)
        {
            ++col;
            cout << g;
            cout << "\n";
            i = g;
            *(A+1000) = i;
        }
        else
        {
            i = g;
        }

    }
    return *(A+1000);
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    int *C = new int[1000];
    int *B=new int[1000];
    *(B+1000) = idealne(*(C+1000));
    for ( i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        cout << *(B+i); 
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Чисто ради интереса, что вам пришло в голову, когда вы прочитали текст ошибки?

Answer (score 2):

```
int idealne()
```

У вас функция не принимает аргументов
Но тут решили выполнить функцию с аргументом

```
dealne(*(C+1000));
```